# Adding Where in a SelectList with OrderBy in LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

This code is already working, but how do I add the `WHERE` clause in my existing LINQ?

```
ViewBag.UserType= new SelectList(_odb.USR_TYP_MSTR.OrderBy(o => o.USR_TYP_ID), "USR_TYP_ID", "USR_TYP_DESC");
```

Comment: `_odb.USR_TYP_MSTR.Where(o => o....).OrderBy(o => o.USR_TYP_ID)` ?

Comment: @FarhadJabiyev thanks! But what do I put in the parameter of `WHERE` if I want it to be like PARAM_CD = "BP_TYP"?

Comment: Just add Where(d=>d.PARAM_CD=="BP_TYP")

Comment: Thanks to both of you guys! Would be better if you posted it as answer instead here in comment section. I'll try it after I finish my controller :)

Answer (score 1):

```
ViewBag.UserType= new SelectList(_odb.USR_TYP_MSTR.Where(o => o.USR_TYP_ID ==1 ).OrderBy(o => o.USR_TYP_ID), "USR_TYP_ID", "USR_TYP_DESC");
```

Comment: Sorry for the noob question, but what does `<predicate>` mean? Btw, the answer from the comment section already worked. Thanks for your help, man :)

Comment: predicate is your condition which is applied to each element of List. Only those elements which satisfy the condition are returned. I have added a condition to return only those elements which have `USR_TYP_ID` value equal to 1